# Transfering a block of data from a microcontroller to a PC using the serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, microcontroller

In my project I have a microcontroller that I need to query for a fixed amount of data. The MCU is and STM32 and my GUI application is based on Qt framework.

There is a buffer of 16bit data in the microcontroller that gets filled by some data. I have defined it like this:

```
uint16_t buffer[0xFFFF] = { 0 };
```

Everything works fine in the micro and debugger shows that the buffer contains correct data after some operation/calculation phase.

But now I need to transfer this buffer into a PC using serial port. My question is what would be the correct approach to make sure I get each and every data of this buffer correctly in my GUI application?

This should be as fast as possible (the baud rate is 115200) and as safe as possible e.g. all the 65536 elements should be transferred into the PC in correct order (to draw a waveform out of them).

So, how should I approach this? e.g:

- Do I need a synchronous or asynchronous connection?
- Should I send each element one by one and wait for a ACK from PC for next transmit?
- How it can be implemented in burst mode?
- Do I need to make a kind of packet, e.g. 6 bytes

  - _START_BYTE_ . _COUNTER_H_ . _COUNTER_L_ .  _DATA_H_ . _DATA_L_ . _END_BYTE_

I am not asking for code (yet I appreciate it). I am interested to know the best possible approach!

Comment: Note that saying you want as fast and safe as possible is meaningless. You need to pick one that is more important, because to solution can differ based on your choice.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a buffer size of 65535 elements on a microcontroller??

Comment: @A.R.C. well when it has 1mb ram its ok I think!

Comment: A packet approach for this type of interface is always a good idea.  You have to establish the buffer start in some way anyway.  My preference is start indicator, length and some sort of checksum.  If the length is always known/fixed then skip that.

Comment: @DEKKER 1mb ram ok, which model are you using?

Comment: Why do you use 0xffff (65535 elements) and not 0x10000 (65536)?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need a synchronous or asynchronous connection?

UART is always asynchronous, hence the name Universal Asynchronous Receiver-Transmitter.

> Should I send each element one by one and wait for a ACK from PC for next transmit?

This is a safe way to do it. If the PC echoes each character received, the MCU can verify that the data went through correctly. That way you can usually skip checksums. The downside is that you lose half the speed.

> How it can be implemented in burst mode?
>   Do I need to make a kind of packet, e.g. 6 bytes

With some manner of carrier protocol, containing synch, size, data, checksum etc. Might be a bit overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect a USB cable from your PC to the UART peripheral.

Something like this will work

[https://www.amazon.com/3-3V-Serial-Cable-Terminated-Header/dp/B07FXT9YZ5/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1541617175&sr=8-2-spons&keywords=uart+usb&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FXT9YZ5)

To capture the data, you can have a terminal program such as realterm to log the data.

> Do I need a synchronous or asynchronous connection?

Asynchronous

> Should I send each element one by one and wait for a ACK from PC for next transmit?

This will be more complicated than its worth. Your PC is much faster than the micro. It should be able to handle CRC calculations if you decide to use them.

> How it can be implemented in burst mode?

Do you need a burst mode? Unless the analog device you are gathering this information is not gathering data at a constant speed, then burst does not make sense, b/c you can increase the baud up to 921600 baud rate.

> Do I need to make a kind of packet, e.g. 6 bytes

If you are using some type of terminal program such as Realterm, then it handles all that for you since the STM outputs a UART protocol depending on how you initialized the peripheral.

I am not familiar with qt to know if there is a library you can pull from to capture UART protocol.

If you do not need a live graph, you can log the data using Realterm, and then analyze the data later via excel or any other preferred method.

I know that python has great libraries for real time graphing and capturing COM port data.